# Unable to display icon in jetpack compose desktop

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm trying to display icon and text in jetpack compose desktop. However, icon is not appearing in the output window. Following is the code

```
@Composable
fun FileTreeItem(fileDetail: Path) {
    Row( modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp) ) {
        Icon(imageVector = vectorXmlResource("images/folder-black-18dp.svg"),
                modifier = Modifier.width(18.dp))
        Text(fileDetail.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The API needs vector XML. Online SVG to XML converters can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Put the **XML** version of your **SVG** file in the `resources` folder and named it as `ic_file`. Then write the below code:

```
@Composable
fun FileTreeItem(fileDetail: Path) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp) ) {
        Icon(
            painter = svgResource("ic_file"),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.width(18.dp)
        )

        Text(fileDetail.toString())
    }
}
```